# Pycharm color highlighting for function arguments with default values

Tags: python, linux, ide, pycharm, color-scheme

I have a very annoying problem with my color-scheme in Pycharm (I'm using 5.03 on Arch Linux).

So my arguments with default values not highlighted. For example this code:

```
class Profit:

    def __init__(self, date=datetime.date.today(), amount=0.0, currency='sdf'):
        self.date = date
        self.amount = amount
        self.currency = currency
```

However, when I type quote and variable itself, it becomes green (I use darcula theme) for a short moment and then color gone. Same goes with default int variable, it becomes blue just for a moment.

I've tried to drop all settings, invalidate cache and reinstall Pycharm from scratch, nothing helps me.

All other highlighting works good.

P.S. even StackOverflow highlights it.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Try reporting it on the JetBrains forums, or, as it's open source, you could submit a patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, they've fixed it in 5.04 build: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+143.1919.1+Release+Notes

Also there is a workaround for this: you can remove Foreground for Parameter in `Colors/Fonts` settings in `Python` section.

So now it works like a charm.